# Java read text file and replace & with &amp

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to read a text file using a java trying to replace `&` character with `&amp` since the text file already have `&amp`, `&apos`, `&quot`, `&lt` and `&gt`. 
I want to replace only the & with &amp and skip `&amp`, `&apos`, `&quot`, `&lt` and `&gt`

I tried regex search using following regex `&(^?!((amp;)|(apos;)|(quot;)|(gt;)|(lt;)))` to list the `&` symbol.

Is the above regex correct or there a another way where we can search and replace `&` symbol with `&amp`

Thank you in advance.
This is my current code

```
File log= new File("txtfileNameString.txt");
System.out.println("entering Changes &");
FileReader fr = new FileReader(log);
String s;
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
       s=s.replaceAll("&(^?!((amp;)|(apos;)|(quot;)|(lt;)|(gt;))", "&amp;");
       // do something after replace
}
br.close();
```

Comment: Why? If the text file already has XML escapes it is already presumably a correct XML file,and if it isn't it should be referred to its originator. What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am adding a text block to existing text file with few xml tags

Comment: Then you should do it with the appropriate tools, that will take care of this for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use negative lookahead:

```
s = s.replaceAll("&(?!amp;|apos;|quot;|lt;|gt;)", "&amp;");
```

Comment: i had tried str.replaceAll i did not work for me with above code

Comment: Can you please add a piece of the text you're trying to parse? Maybe you don't have ";" after each symbol?

Comment: generateCounters="false" logString="&amp;&amp;" text="customText & service"

Comment: Thank you @Andrea your screen shot helped i was missing the s=s.replaceAll("&(?!amp;|apos;|quot;|lt;|gt;)", "&amp;");

Comment: Ah, ok, I have understood your doubt. I also edited my original snippet. In fact, Strings in Java are immutable, and they need an explicit assignment (the s = s.replaceAll, in poor words).

Answer (score 0):

```
 FileReader oldfile= new FileWriter("C://users//Chamod//Desktop//testFile.txt");
 String phase  = oldfile.replaceAll("&", "&amp;");

 FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C://users//Chamod//Desktop//testFile.txt");
 writer.write(newFile);
```

Comment: No, this won't work. This will substitute every occurrence of &.

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.